# Comparar linhas entre arquivos .txt

Tags: java

Boa tarde, preciso comparar dois arquivos `.txt` e verificar se cada carácter é igual ao do outro arquivo e armazenar quais caracteres são iguais... Tipo um gabarito

um arquivo `prova.txt` possui o seguinte conteúdo:

```
1;VVFF

2;VFVF

3;FFFV
```

O gabarito possui o conteúdo:

```
1;VVFF

2;FFVV

3;FFFF
```

Fazer uma comparação e somar quantas respostas acertaram

```
int pontuacao = 0;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String gabaritoVetor[] = new String[3];
String notaVetor[] = new String[3];

for (int c = 0; c < gabaritoVetor.length; c++) {
    gabaritoVetor[c] = leitura; //recebe os dados do prova.txt

}
for (int i = 0; i < notaVetor.length; i++) {
    notaVetor[i] = leitura2; //recebe os dados do gabarito.txt
    if (notaVetor[i].equals(gabaritoVetor[i])) {
        pontuacao++;
    }
}

System.out.println("\nPontuação: " + pontuacao);
```

Testei com os arquivos iguais deu certo, quando modifiquei deu `Pontuação = 0`
Se os arquivos forem iguais mostra `Pontuação = 3`

Alguma ideia???

Comment: Penso que ele está a comparar cada linha do ficheiro, e não cada caracter.

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode usar o método split da classe String para limpar o arquivo ([leia mais sobre o método](http://blog.alura.com.br/como-separar-palavras-de-string-em-java/)). Com o split eu consegui isolar apenas as respostas da prova e do gabarito, então comparei char a char, usando o método chartAt da classe string. Obs: não fiz o método para ler o arquivo texto, pois acredito que esse não é seu problema.

```
package teste2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeitorArquivo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] gabarito = new String[3];
        String [] prova = new String[3];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int pontuacao = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < prova.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Entre com o gabarito da alternativa " + (i+1));
            gabarito[i] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Entre com as respostas da alternativa " + (i+1));
            prova[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < prova.length; i++) {
            String respostaProva = prova[i].split(";")[1];
            String respostaGabarito = gabarito[i].split(";")[1];

            for (int j = 0; j < respostaProva.length(); j++) {
                if(respostaProva.charAt(j) == respostaGabarito.charAt(j))
                    pontuacao++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Pontuação final é: " + pontuacao);

        sc.close();
    }

}
```